# Guice MapBinder with list values

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, multimap

I have a service which needs injection of mulitmap - `Map<String, List<Enricher>>`

```
public class EnrichService {
    private Map<String, List<Enricher>> typeEnrichers;

    @Inject
    public EnrichService(Map<String, List<Enricher>> typeEnrichers) {
        this.typeEnrichers = typeEnrichers;
    }

    public void enrich(Entity entity) {
        List<Enricher> enrichers = typeEnrichers.get(entity.type);
        //.. enriching entity with enrichers
    }
}

class Entity {
    String id;
    String type = "shapedColorful";
    String color;
    String shape;
}

interface Enricher {
    void enrich(Entity entity);
}

class ColorEnricher implements Enricher {
    @Inject
    private  ColorService colorService;
    public void enrich(Entity entity) {
        entity.color = colorService.getColor(entity.id);
    }
}

class ShapeEnricher implements Enricher {
    @Inject
    private ShapeService shapeService;
    public void enrich(Entity entity) {            
        entity.shape = shapeService.getShape(entity.id);
    }
}
```

I need help with configuring typeEnrichers binder in juice
Here is what I'm trying, but stuck

```
bind(ColorService).to(ColorServiceImpl.class);
bind(ShapeService).to(ShapeServiceImpl.class);
MapBinder<RelationType, List<Enricher>> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(
            binder(), 
            new TypeLiteral<String>() {},
            new TypeLiteral<List<Enricher>>() {});

mapBinder.addBinding("shapedColorful", to(/*how to bind list of Enrichers here??*/))
```

Any help, how I can bind such multimap?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying mix together `MapBinder` with `Multibinder`.

I would suggest you to create a `Provider` for each MapBinder relation. Actually `Multibinder` is a List `Provider` itself, to be specific its `RealMultibinder` implementation unfortunatelly is package private and forbidden from use. If it would not be package private maybe we could use it this way. Most likely it would not work anyway... Imho, it would be nice.

```
bind(ColorService).to(ColorServiceImpl.class);
bind(ShapeService).to(ShapeServiceImpl.class);
MapBinder<RelationType, List<Enricher>> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(
            binder(), 
            new TypeLiteral<String>() {},
            new TypeLiteral<List<Enricher>>() {});

mapBinder.addBinding("shapedColorful", toProvider(Multibinder.newSetBinder(this.binder(), Enricher.class).addBinding().to(ColorService.class).addBinding().to(ShapeService.class).asEagerSingleton()))
```

**You can still create a provider and use it:**

```
public class ShapeColorfulProvider implements Provider<List<Enricher>> {
 @Inject private ColorService colorService;
 @Inject private ShapeService shapeService;

 public List<Enricher> get() {
   return Lists.newArrayList(colorService,shapeService);
 }

}
```

then

```
   mapBinder.addBinding("shapedColorful", toProvider(ShapeColorfulProvider.class))
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but I need to store generic objects in the map i.e. "Map<String, List<Enricher<X,Y>>>"